# How to use Lua 5.2 with luasocket 3

Tags: windows, lua, luasocket, lua-5.2

I am trying to compile [luasocket 3](https://github.com/diegonehab/luasocket/tree/master/src) that I found on GitHub with [lua 5.2](http://www.lua.org/download.html). Problem is, I'm not sure how to bind together `Lua` with `luasocket`. Do I need to compile `luasocket` as DLL and then reference if somewhere in `lua` code, or should I just call it from lua console?

Comment: Have you tried building it with luarocks? There is a rockspec in the repo.

Comment: Is there any tutorial on how to do this? I'm a newbie with Lua

Answer (score 4):

Try installing it using [luarocks](http://luarocks.org). If you don't have luarocks, install it following instructions on the site.

Then download the rockspec file(luasocket-scm-0.rockspec) from luasocket repo and run

```
$ luarocks install *path to the rockspec file*
```

If everything goes OK, you'll be able to use luasocket from Lua like this:

```
local socket = require "socket"
-- now you can use socket.xxx functions
```

Comment: I think you need to setup package.cpath before calling require

Answer (score 3):

Usually you only need to reference lua include files (there are only 4 needed: `luaconf.h`, `lua.h`, `lualib.h`, and `lauxlib.h`) and library/dll (-llua52 in your case). You don't say what compiler you are using, so it's difficult to be more specific, but I have [script(s)](https://github.com/pkulchenko/ZeroBraneStudio/tree/master/build/) that build luasocket with lua5.2 on Windows using mingw (and using gcc on OSX/Linux). For example, to compile on Windows, you can get `build-win32.sh` script and run it as: `bash build-win32.sh 5.2 lua luasocket`. It will get all the files needed (using wget) and compile everything in `deps/` folder; the resulting executable and libraries will be put in `../bin` folder.

You can also get compiled libraries from the same [repository](https://github.com/pkulchenko/ZeroBraneStudio/tree/master/bin).