# installing lua socket lib

Tags: sockets, lua, luasocket

I am trying to install luasocket, but it I can't find any info how to do this. I downloaded from luaforge luasocket-2.0.2.tar.gz archive, but there is no configure file, only MVS solutions. So, how to get compiled libs?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to use Lua 5.2 with luasocket 3](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18653212/how-to-use-lua-5-2-with-luasocket-3)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can install LuaSocket via LuaRocks:

```
luarocks install luasocket
```

or directly from git:

```
luarocks install https://raw.githubusercontent.com/diegonehab/luasocket/master/luasocket-scm-0.rockspec
```

Answer (score 0):

This has already been discussed previously on SO; see for example [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18653212/how-to-use-lua-5-2-with-luasocket-3) and its answers.

Note that this is not the latest version of luasocket and it's not compatible with Lua 5.2 or Lua 5.3. You can get the more recent version from [this repository](https://github.com/diegonehab/luasocket).